# How can i sort return values asc order on mysql with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have 2 tables 1 for product cats, other for products in mysql. If my parent category hasn't got any product, i have to fetch sub category's product from mysql. I successfully achieved it. But in sub categories products method, product's are coming first; first categories products, then other categories product. My method looks like;

```
public function getProductsByCat($productCatID) {
    $lang = LanguageController::detectLang();
    $visibility = VIS;
    $this->prepare('SELECT product_details.*, product_details_lang.*, product_cat_lang.*
                    FROM product_details
                    INNER JOIN product_details_lang 
                    ON product_details.product_id = product_details_lang.product_id
                    INNER JOIN product_cat_lang
                    ON product_details.product_cat_id = product_cat_lang.product_cat_id
                    WHERE product_cat_lang.product_cat_id = :productCatID
                    AND product_details_lang.product_lang_iso =  :lang
                    AND product_details_lang.visibility = :visibility
                    ORDER BY `product_details`.`product_name` ASC');
    // Binding Values
    $this->bindParam(':productCatID',$productCatID);
    $this->bindParam(':lang',$lang);
    $this->bindParam(':visibility',$visibility);
    $this->execute();
    // Executing Query
    $this->param = $this->fetchAll();
    return $this->param;
```

I use method in my view:

```
$products->getProductsByCat($subProductCat->product_cat_id);
foreach ($products->param as $product) {
    echo $product->product_name'\n';
}
```

But products are coming in category list order. I want to order them `product_name` with `ascending` order. When i `var_dump($product)` The result is;

```
object(stdClass)[12]
public 'product_id' => string '145' (length=3)
public 'product_cat_id' => string '6' (length=1)
public 'product_name' => string 'TK001' (length=5)
public 'order_id' => string '145' (length=3)
public 'id' => string '6' (length=1)
public 'product_lang_iso' => string 'tr' (length=2)
public 'product_lang_name' => string 'TK001' (length=5)
public 'product_lang_link' => string 'tk001' (length=5)
public 'product_code' => string '' (length=0)
public 'product_type' => string '' (length=0)
public 'product_volume' => string '' (length=0)
public 'product_package' => string '' (length=0)
public 'add_user' => string '1' (length=1)
public 'add_date' => string '2015-04-10 20:46:06' (length=19)
public 'upd_user' => string '1' (length=1)
public 'upd_date' => string '2015-04-10 20:46:06' (length=19)
public 'visibility' => string '1' (length=1)
public 'product_cat_lang_iso' => string 'tr' (length=2)
public 'product_cat_lang_name' => string 'Çelik Tencere Kulpları' (length=24)
public 'product_cat_lang_link' => string 'celik-tencere-kulplari' (length=22)
public 'product_cat_lang_content' => string 'Çelik Tencere Kulpları' (length=24)
```

Any help will greatly appricated.

Thx in advance.

Comment: for join operation of product and category table the result will come category wise and then name wise ascending. am I right?

Comment: What do you mean by category list? If you are searching for products in one category?

Comment: @AntonM. no there are 2 `foreach` loops one for sub categories, other for sub categories' products. i'm searching products in more then 2 categories.

Comment: @ShaymolBapary yeah you are right

Comment: Then may be collect categoryIds and one sql with product_cat_id in ({ids}), then mysql will sort it.

Comment: @AntonM. i dont want to sort it on mysql. I want to sort it with php.